# Continuity of Sup on a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$f$ is continuous function when $x \in [a,b]$ show that $M(x)=\sup\{ f(y):y \in [a,x]\}$ is continuous in $[a,b]$
Can someone help me to prove this ?
 It seems simple but I can`t get started. I was far from real analysis for years, I Did not find a clue

Comment: Start by writing down what you have to prove, in terms of $\varepsilon$ and $\delta.$